# Security of Javascript: Edit JS code for form validation in browser then submit the form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a concern about security of JavaScript. It seems that one can edit the JavaScript code in browser to alter form validations so that he can submit something bad. I know that back-end validation is also necessary and important, but is there a way to prevent such modification of JS code at the front-end? Because, otherwise it seems like the effort paid to implement front-end validation with JavaScript can be easily wasted.

Comment: No, there's nothing you can do to prevent it. Input checking on the client is just a convenience, not a security feature.

Comment: No. Any attempt to prevent this modification is doomed to failure. That's why you must always re-validate the data on the server side as well

Comment: You must always validate server-side, but the JS validation isn't wasted effort because (assuming you do it right) it makes things nicer for regular users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript form validation is not meant to be your application's form of security. It's purpose is for a cleaner user experience that gracefully notifies the user of errors/progress/requirements of the form itself.

NEVER rely on client-side code as a point of security in your applications because, by nature, you're giving that code to everyone.

Also, don't think of it as a waste of effort. The more polite your app is in notifying and guiding what the user must do to properly fill out your forms, the better.

True security for your application must happen on the server side (PHP, Ruby, Nodejs, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript validation used to validate the fields in client side to make validation faster instead of sending the request to the server and waiting for the response, Your server side security should not depend on the security of the Javascript, you should validate all submitted data to the server in back-end .

you can compress javascript file to get the mini file to make it little bit harder not to prevent the attack.